# Save hotkey screenshot in pyautogui

Tags: python, screenshot, pyautogui

I have taken a screenshot using hotkeys in pyautogui, as that way I was able to get only the window content. Now I don't seem to be able to save it. Am I doing something wrong or is there any way to get the screenshot?

```
screenshot = pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'printscreen')
screenshot.save('temp.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exspression `pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'printscreen')` retuns nothing, so you can't save image from it.

Simplest solution I could find is to install some extra modules:

`pip install pillow keyboard`

Module `keyboard` is used to create smarter hotkey with python function as callback.

Such function shoul press `Print Screen` to save image to clipboard, then we can get image from clipboard with `PIL` module and save it to file.

Here is the example:

```py
import time

import pyautogui
import keyboard

from PIL import ImageGrab

def save_screenshoot():
    pyautogui.press('printscreen')
    im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
    im.save('screenshoot.png','PNG')

keyboard.add_hotkey('alt', save_screenshoot)

while True:
    # While this loop is active 'alt' wil save screenshoot
    time.sleep(5)
```